# Pointers notation in c

Tags: c, pointers

Good morning,
Are the 3 notations here below exactly equivalent?

```
char *pc;
char * pc;
char* pc;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: All same code.

Style `char *pc;` matches the C standard.

`char * pc;` is [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_vs_AHA_solutions)

Comment: Why don't you try? https://godbolt.org/z/W5YhzoTo7